# pgfplots: Why does samples quantity has such effect on the shape of the plot?

Tags: pgfplots

By varying the value of the samples in drawing such plot in pgfplots, the shape of the plots changes so much; is it because of some instability in drawing plots or the function has such behaviour? From where such variation rises?

[image]
[image]

```
% pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(deg(#1))*sqrt(abs(cos(deg(#1)))))/(sin(deg(#1))+8/5)-1.5*sin(deg(#1))+1.5}}
\begin{axis}
        [hide axis,scale=0.3,title=10]
        \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=10,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\hspace*{3cm}
\begin{axis}
        [hide axis,scale=0.3,title=50]
        \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\hspace*{3cm}
\begin{axis}
        [hide axis,scale=0.3,title=100]
        \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\hspace*{3cm}
\begin{axis}
        [hide axis,scale=0.3,title=500]
        \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=500,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\hspace*{3cm}
\begin{axis}
        [hide axis,scale=0.3,title=1000]
        \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=1000,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Even in higher values of samples, we see a little change exists in the :

[image]

Comment: Consider drawing a circle by connecting straight line segments... How many segments would it take until you had a perfect circle, or even a passable circle? Now consider drawing the more complicated shape here by connecting straight line segments. The number of these segments is similar in concept to the number of samples required to draw a smooth curve here

Comment: @darthbith I know, but at some point the shape should converge; however, as you see at samples 1000 and 2000, the shape still changes.... How can we conclude that no instability exists and it is only because lower number of segments have been taken to draw the shape? How can we be sure?

Comment: What happens at 3000? 5000? 10000? I bet it will converge. Sharp points like that are always very difficult. Nonetheless, I see your point about instability in the choice of the samples close to the point.

Comment: @darthbith Scientifically and generally speaking, how can we research instability of functions? I have never seen any reference about this.

Comment: Use odd numbered samples

Comment: @percusse why?...

Comment: I think the problem is due to [smooth] since there are two locations where the slope is discontinuous.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfmathdeclarefunction{R}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(sin(deg(#1))*sqrt(abs(cos(deg(#1)))))/(sin(deg(#1))+8/5)-1.5*sin(deg(#1))+1.5}}
\begin{axis}
        [hide axis,scale=0.3,title={20 with bilateral symmetry}]
        \addplot [domain=-pi/2:pi/2,samples=10,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
        \addplot [domain=pi/2:3*pi/2,samples=10,data cs=polarrad,solid, thick,red,fill=red,smooth] {R(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: heart]